# Тег <header>. Количество тега header

Tags: html

Может быть несколько тегов header на сайте, если да, то каким образом это может быть реализовано, и стоит ли вообще добавлять больше одного header на сайт? Могли бы привести в пример html разметку для наглядного понимания

Comment: Сколько хотите, столько и используйте. `<html><body><header></header><header></header></body></html>`

Answer (score 1):

Тег `header`, как и остальные теги в html разметке, может повторяться столько, сколько вам потребуется. Этот тег был задуман для логического разделения структуры страницы, для выделения заголовка страницы, так как большинство веб-страниц содержат структуру "header -> content -> footer".

Разумеется, **вы не ограничены в повторении использования тега**, но, это означает, что логически нарушается структура страницы.